# system.data.sqlite: How to obtain the result of pragma foreign_keys without a connection to a database?

Tags: c#, system.data.sqlite, pragma

Using the sqlite3 command line interface I can type 'pragma foreign_keys' and see the result without opening a database. How can I do this in C# using system.data.sqlite?

Thanks

Adrian

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to your connection string:

```
var cnnString = "...;PRAGMA foreign_keys=1"
```

for example.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made myself clearer. I am trying to test if the version of SQLite I have supports foreign keys. I wish to test this in a C# program without connecting to a database. PRAGMA foreign_keys will return null if foreign keys are not supported.